# Calculate $\sqrt{{{a+x^2}\over x} - 2\sqrt{a}} +\sqrt{{{a+x^2}\over x} + 2\sqrt{a}}$ if $a>0$ and $x>\sqrt{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Firstly I put this to be equal to some "dummy y" and then I squared both sides to get squared binomial on one side and $y^2$ on the other. When I simplified this problem I went to solution of $y = 2{\sqrt{a}\over x}$, but it is not the answer as I looked in solution book (Answer is $2\sqrt{x}$). I repeated this process three times, and I always get the same solution and it seems to me that I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$${{a+x^2}\over x} \pm 2\sqrt a=\dfrac{a+x^2\pm2\sqrt a x}x=\left(\dfrac{x\pm\sqrt a}{\sqrt x}\right)^2$$

and for real $u, \sqrt{u^2}=|u|$

and for $u\ge0, |u|=+u$

Comment: No, "for real $u$", $|u|$ is not $+u$.

Comment: @Did, Rectified.

Comment: So is it, or not?

Comment: @GreatDuke, what's your question?

Comment: I managed to solve this task,no questions, thank a lot!